# Questions about XNA, bvh, 3dsmax, FBX, biped, CAT objects, Poser, makehuman, lip sync etc

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-7, xna

Questions regarding XNA and skinned animations.

My main objective is to create a biped with my wifes face on it and apply bvh files to it to use in some wp7 game/app... So I have gotten confused about some thing on the way..

I notice some programs like poser, makehuman, turbosquid free characters can export characters with 'bones'... How do you apply a bvh to bones? Do the bones need to be set up in some specific way?  Do you load the bones and load the bvh file and somehow map them together??  I know 3dsmax bipeds are more ready for .bip files and .bvh but nothing exports in that format.. so unless I am creating it from scratch it seems I need to find a way to get these bones to work with bvh files...

What about Biped and CAT objects? When I export ythose as a FBX file can I use the with the 'skinned animation' XNA sample?  Or must it be 3dsmax 'bones' ?

I tried Poser but when I got from .DAE -> 3ds max -> fbx -> 'skinned animation' the geometry is all messed up for some reason... but the nice thing about poser is the ease I can add bvh files plus I can map a face photo and easily texture the face...

Morph target possible in XNA? I don't think so.. So I guess the easiest way to lip sync is create a bone in the mouth and programmatically move it during audio playback  ?

Any other tools out there that would be helpful or samples ?

Comment: Does your wife know about this? :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never had any experience with what you're trying to attain, but I did come across this extensive thread on the AppHub forums about facial animation and morph targets:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/32219.aspx

Here's an interesting quote from Jon Watte:

> The XNA Model content format does not
> support morph targets. The X file
> format does not support morph targets.
> The XNA importer for FBX and X
> geometry does not support morph
> targets. Thus, anything you do will
> have to be custom at some level.

Thread goes on for 75 posts, so hopefully you'll find something of interest in there ... good luck!

Comment: thnaks ill check it out .. strange morph targets are not supported.. doesnt seem that complex...  I think Quake 3 used them. .. or maybe it was called vertex animation back then